# YouTube asks me "Are you still here?" after each video in a playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I use YouTube to listen to music and I have some playlists. But today, after each song, it stops and I get the question "Are you still here?" and I have to confirm in order to continue playing.

Did you notice this?

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/183897 and so far it's been working for me very fine.

If anyone notices bugs or something, please tell me.

Comment: It's not working anymore :(

Comment: Still working for me. Can you describe what happens?

EDIT
Let's rather takes that tp private messages or mail.